# W/Choreographer error in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have developed an application that works great on several phones. But on one model, I get this error. Can anybody help me decrypting it ? I don't understand how to fix it.

```
Frame time is 0.77418 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.
```

Comment: What model it is? And what's the android version of it?

Comment: TCT ONE TOUCH 4015D Android 4.2.2, Alcatel. My app runs correctly on Android 2.3.5 to 5.1